# undefined method `<<' for {}:Hash

Tags: ruby

I was trying the following code:

```
a = Hash.new
a << "Bom dia!" # => NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for {}:Hash
```

Any idea why it returns 'undefined method'?

Comment: because that method doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are trying to assign values for a [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html) using `<<` (shovel operator).

Instead, try assigning them like this: (There should be *key/value* pairs in a `Hash`)

```
a = Hash.new
a[:foo] = "Bom dia!"
```

or,

```
a = {foo: "Bom dia!"}
```

Answer (score 5):

[Hash](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/Hash.html) doesn't have a `<<` method.

I guess the real question is why you think it does, and what you think should happen if you `<<` a string to an object that consists of key/value pairs.

Is it possible you meant to do the following?

```
a = Array.new
```